# GraylogHttp dosen't expand formatted string from Common Logging

Tags: c#, nlog, graylog

I have a Graylog logging server set up for all our projects. One of the projects is using NLog and it uses a framework with Common Logging.

When the framework logs, the messsage received in Graylog is {0}. So somewhere it's string formatting not done.

If i configure a parameter and send in $(message) there, the expanded message is sent.

Also, the colored console configured works as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog throwExceptions="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.GraylogHttp"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="graylog" xsi:type="GraylogHttp" facility="Superman" 
            graylogServer="http://xxxxxx.stackhero-network.com" graylogPort="xxxx">
      <parameter name="real_message" layout="${longdate}|${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}|${message}" />
      <parameter name="source_method" layout="${callsite}" />
    </target>
    <target name="coloredConsole" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" useDefaultRowHighlightingRules="false"
            layout="${longdate}|${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}|${message}" >
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Debug" foregroundColor="DarkGray" />
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Info" foregroundColor="Gray" />
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Warn" foregroundColor="Yellow" />
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Error" foregroundColor="Red" />
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Fatal" foregroundColor="Red" backgroundColor="White" />
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" appendTo="graylog"/>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" appendTo="coloredConsole"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

The code used for calling looks like this (Relevant parts...)

```
using Common.Logging;
internal static ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger<SboApp>();
Logger.Error($"UI Connect Error: {ex.Message}", ex);
```

I'm using

- Common.Logging.NLog4412 v 3.4.1
- NLog v 4.4.12
- NLog.Targets.GraylogHttp v 0.0.24

What am i doing wrong

Comment: Could you please show the logger call?

Comment: Hi @Julian, I have edited the question with a call example from the framework.

Comment: From your question, it's hard to understand what the issue is... are messages getting through to graylog?

Comment: Maybe try logging to console or file, then you know if the problem is in common logging or the graylog http target.

Comment: As noted in the question, the logger called coloredConsole works as expected.

Messages do arrive at Graylog, but they is all "{0}", that is the whole message. Like a not expanced format string.